# Control Android phone via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I  have a Samsung Bluetooth device. Using the device I can pair it with my Android phone and I can listen to music from my Samsung Bluetooth device which is playing on the Android device.  I am not installing any software on my android device.

Now my question is how can the Samsung Bluetooth device control the Android music player and also incoming calls?

Remember I am not installing any software on the Android device.

FYI: I can connect the Samsung Bluetooth device to any phone like a Nokia, iPhone, Android etc. but I want to know about Android.

Answer (score 1):

Agree, you are not installing any application for playing music. What actual happens in the background is your device is connected via Bluetooth API.

Music is playing in the android phone ( or any other phone ), only the sound signals gets transfer to your bluetooth device, which is later played by your bluetooth device ( which is either bluetooth based speakerphone or headphone).

Moreover when you click "Next","Previous", Volumn + or - button in your device, an signal is sent via bluetooth to your phone which acts same operation in phone.

Comment: Thanks bro for answer,It means If I want to control another device's music player I can do it via android bluetooth api. am I right?

Comment: Yes, but for that you need to do code, for the receiving signals

Comment: I didn't get you about signals I mean what type of signals? I have tried it with android Bluetooth adapter but it's not working. My researched said that I require special Api to transfer audio data. but which I don't know.

Comment: that means, if you press any key on bluetooth device , it generate a code suppose on key 1 it generates "1" and send it to your android device, so on android phone side you need to take care of this received "1" , likewise other signals

Comment: Yes. That is my point. to android device I am not doing any code. so  i cannot take care for any received signal in android device.